# Powershell : set (OneDrive) status property on file

Tags: .net, powershell, explorer

I am coding a OneDrive replica with PowerShell, giving me access to my self-hosted NAS.

I am trying to make PowerShell interact with the `status` column in Explorer.

[image: status column in explorer.exe]

Is there a way to control this using PowerShell ?